# How do I implement Domain Driven Design by Eric Evan's using Spring-Data-JPA and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, domain-driven-design, spring-data

I learnt about DDD from Eric Evan's book and [Martin fowlers blog on "AnemicDomainModel"](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)

I googled but could not find a example on how we can implement DDD using Spring-data-jpa and hibernate.

All the current solutions about DDD using Spring and Hibernate are not using spring-data-jpa in their implementation.

Do you know how to implement DDD using spring-data-jpa?

Comment: Down voters please explain why you are down voting so I can explain myself.

Comment: Let me rephrase your question:"I want to build a great car. Do you know how to build it using a screwdriver"? Btw, DDD is about _design_ regardless of the language/library used. It's a mindset.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to model your domain without really caring about technologies like spring and hibernate. When you want technology specific solutions ask yourself "what am I trying to achieve with this tech". For example instead of asking how do I do DDD with hibernate, rather ask how do I implement the repository pattern and unit of work with hibernate.